# How to use a huge array in HLSL (error X4505)

Tags: arrays, directx, shader, hlsl

When I try to compile I get the error:

> X4505: sum of temp register and indexable temp registers exceeds limit
>   of 4096.

However my **shader** does work in **FX Composer**.

The reason it crashes is probably because I use a very large array since I'm using marching cubes.

```
const static int edgeTable[256] = ...
const static int triTable[256][16] = ...
```

How should I go about using these arrays? (D11)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476898(v=vs.85).aspx#Shader_Constant_Buffer: Each shader stage allows up to 15 shader-constant buffers; each buffer can hold up to 4096 constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I actually solved this problem a few days after posting this (a few allnighters) and forgot to upload the solution.
By now I have forgotten what it exactly was so I'm putting up my whole solution: https://github.com/Ownie/MarchingCubesShader

Answer (score -2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476898(v=vs.85).aspx#Shader_Constant_Buffer

> Each shader stage allows up to 15 shader-constant buffers; each buffer can hold up to 4096 constants.

Comment: So? _How to use a huge array in HLSL (error X4505)_