# one int variable works as an array index but another one doesn't

Tags: hlsl, marching-cubes

I'm working on a marching cube compute shader in unity at some point i need to find an index so that i can make vertices by connecting those edges here is the code

```
uint cubeIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (cube[i].isInside == 1)
    {
        cubeIndex |= 1 << i;
    }
}

    return cubeIndex;
```

the problem is when i use "cubeIndex" as an array index it gives me this error:
Program 'CSMain', error X4505: Sum of temp registers and indexable temp registers exceeds limit of 4096 at kernel CSMain.

if change the array index to any other int the code works!

here is my main kernel

```
 uint myCubeIndex = CubeInit(cube);
Edges midPoints = CalMidPoints(cube);

int edge = triTable[myCubeIndex][0];

float3 position = midPoints.midPoints[edge];

vertexArray.Append(position);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the bitshift with the unit is either going into the negatives giving you an overflow. or !!

[How to use a huge array in HLSL (error X4505)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732465/how-to-use-a-huge-array-in-hlsl-error-x4505)

this issue as someone over here also tried to put too many vertices in a hlsl shader trying to make marching cubes work and needed to limit it to 4096

Comment: i don't understand how it could become a negative number the loop can only shift it 8 digits left at most is there some rule i'm not aware of ?

Comment: In certain languages I do not remember exactly how it works but here is the basic concept. left most bit represents the sign so 1|0001  would be a +1 now if you reach 1|1111 and but shift again it needs to use a bigger bitesize so it will add 0's accordingly like 
0011|1111 making the left-most digit a 0 representing a negative number. 
sorry, this is not a good example as I do not remember the exacts. I would say try long unsigned int but marching cube uses bigger values still.